# multiple condition in r

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

is there a better way to have multiple condition in order to simplify my code.
here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(dx1 <- c("a", "b", "c"),
                   dx2 <- c("b", "c", "d"),
                   dx3 <- c("a", "f", "g"))

condition <- c("a", "b")

# This is what I want to simplify
test[,dx4 := ifelse(dx1 %in% condition|
                    dx2 %in% condition |
                    dx3 %in% condition, 1, 0)]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `|`.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` (not needed if all the columns are used), loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), check whether the the 'condition' elements are `%in%` the column, `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` with `|` and convert to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
test[, dx4 := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, condition))), .SDcols = dx1:dx3]
test
#   dx1 dx2 dx3 dx4
#1:   a   b   a   1
#2:   b   c   f   1
#3:   c   d   g   0
```

#### data

```
test <- data.table(dx1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
               dx2 = c("b", "c", "d"),
               dx3 = c("a", "f", "g"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: That's quite a solution. I wanted to point out the mundane: In 'i' a condition can be set to change results for the 'set' command: test[dx1 %in% condition,dx4 :=  [what is needed here]]